# why returning data from #temptable instead of @tempTable giving timeout error in ssrs 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I got a report in SSRS 2008, which is including a table, called Results. This table is connected to a Stored Procedure, called MyResults. The SP returns the output like:

```
...
select Name,Group,Amount
from @tabledata
where Amount > 50

END
```

where @tabledata is a "table" type of variable. When the SP is like that, everything is working very well. However, I am changing the SP like:

```
...
select Name,Group,Amount
into #temp
from @tabledata
where Amount > 50

select * from #temp

END
```

After this change, when I try to refresh the dataset in the SSRS, it is giving an error like:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding. Warning: Null value is
>   eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Note that I am trying to change the Time out (in seconds) value from 0 to another values, but it is not helping at all.

What am I doing wrong? Any help/clue would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: and if you use @temp instead?

Comment: I am expected to use a temp table instead of a table type of variable at the end